# S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I am working on a project on django 1.9 and using django-rest-framework.

**Views.py:**

```
@parser_classes((FileUploadParser,))
class upload_image(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['images']
        upload_s3 = FileUpload()
        folder_name = 'images'
        file_url = upload_s3.put(file_obj, folder_name, file_obj.name)
class File_Upload:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = {
            "aws_access_key_id": "*************",
            "aws_secret_access_key": "***********",
            "region_name": "Asia Pacific (Singapore)"
        }
        self.bucketname = "my_bucket"

        self.session = Session(**self.env)

        self.s3_client = self.session.client('s3')

    def put(self, bytes, folder, file_name):
        self.s3_client.put_object(Body=bytes, Bucket=self.bucketname, Key=folder + "/" + file_name)
        return "https://s3.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s/%s" % (self.env['region_name'], self.bucketname, folder, file_name)
```

On python shell I am able to upload as well as download images to and from amazon s3. I am using boto for this.

Below is the code that I am using :

```
>>> import boto
>>> import sys
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
>>> from boto.s3.key import Key
>>> conn = boto.connect_s3("ACESS_KEY_ID","SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",host="s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",is_secure = False)
>>> k = bucket.get_key("KEY_NAME")
>>> k.get_contents_to_filename("test.file")
>>> k.set_canned_acl('public-read')
>>> url = k.generate_url(0,query_auth=False,force_http=True)
```

I get a working url. But the problem comes when I want to do the same in the views.py(above code), I get this error:

> S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request 
>   Request Method:   POST Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/imagedata/image/add/ 
>   Django Version:    1.9 
>   Exception Type:   S3ResponseError 
>   Exception Value:  S3ResponseError: 400 
>   Bad Request 
>   Exception Location:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py in_get_key_internal, line 235 
>   Python Executable: /usr/bin/python Python Version: 2.7.10

kindly tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ???

Comment: yes, I solved this problem but sorry I don't remember how I did. I should have written the answer that time only :(